# Is "Though sometimes" idiomatic here?

Tags: idiomatic-language

A: What's wrong?

B: I just had a long day.

A: I thought you liked your job?

B: I do. Though sometimes it can get tiring having to interact with customers all day.

Is the last statement phrased idiomatically, in particular "though sometimes"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  "Sometimes it can get tiring having to interact with customers all day" is a grammatical clause.  "Though" is a subordinating conjunction, joining that clause to the "Yes."

Both constructions are common enough to be idiomatic.